# Transferring Data From One MySQL Table To Another

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I have a database that has a notice_current table and a notices_archive table.  As part of a user logout process, I want to move all of their associated notices from the current table to the archive.

In my PHP application code I am currently making a transaction where I copy the notices over, and then delete the rows in the notices_current table if there were no errors in the copying.  However, I am wondering if MySQL has some innate function or method for simply pushing notices from one table to another.  If so, it would see that this would be more effective than my current implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not a single built-in function for this, but if you're currently iterating over all of the rows, then something like this might be a lot more efficient:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO notices_archive SELECT * FROM notice_current WHERE user_id=%;
DELETE FROM notice_current WHERE user_id=%;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks, Ian.  This is actually exactly what I am doing.  Oh well, at least I know I've got the most efficient method down, it seems.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

u can use phpmyadmin tools to do this.
goto phpmy admin then select your source db and click on operation tab and select copy and set the parameters then let phpmyadmin to do his job :D

Comment: Thanks, but I need this process to be automated because it will be in a LogOut class that I am writing.